# Pytorch: Creating a tensor mask based of rate/percentage/ratio

Tags: python, pytorch

How can I generate a mask tensor that has a specific ratio of 0 and 1? For example 70:30 of 0s and 1s in a 5 by 10 tensor will generate:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0],
[1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0],
[0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,0],
[0,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0],
[0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can approximate the ratio using random sampling:

```py
import torch

mask = torch.rand(5, 10)  # uniformly distributed between 0 and 1
mask = mask < 0.3   # 30% pixels "on"
```

On average, `mask` will have the right amount of "on" pixels.

---

Alternatively, if you must have **exactly** 30% of "on" pixels, you can use [`torch.randperm`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.randperm.html#torch.randperm) to randomly permute a mask with exactly the number of "on" pixels:

```py
raw = torch.zeros((5*10,))
raw[:int(0.3 * 5 * 10)] = 1.  # set EXACTLY 30% of the pixels in the mask
ridx = torch.randperm(5*10)   # a random permutation of the entries
mask = torch.reshape(raw[ridx], (5, 10))
```

Comment: It works. Thank you very much.